# Best way to name my distribution on Plone?

Tags: python, package, plone, egg

I work at `Company`, creating project `Project` that implements a functionality. Let's name it `Newsletter`. It could be used in further projects.

I need to create a new Plone Product, but I don't know the best way to do it. I thought about `company.project.newsletter`. I've read somewhere ([@aclark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330827/best-way-to-name-my-distribution-on-plone/6331258#6331258) answer [remembered the link](http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/the-naming-of-things-package-names-and-namespaces)) to not use nested namespaces in my product name "unless I'm 100% certain in what I'm doing".

Can someone guide me with some references about properly naming my Plone packages? I miss a guide like pep8 with some convention. (Specially when there are [completely different opinions about this](http://weblion.psu.edu/3/news/ewr/are-we-overusing-namespace-packages)).

Comment: still uses you: Off topic on SO? Expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development, ask on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are asking about a convention (versus something technical). In short, it doesn't matter. I prefer flat or short namespaces, but they can be as long as you like e.g. https://github.com/aclark4life/viewlets_dont_suck.

In the case of nested namespaces, e.g. plone.*, and plone.app.* the convention has meaning. plone.* are ideally able to be reused out of Plone, whereas plone.app.* packages can only be used in Plone.

Similarly, it's quite common to see company branded namespaces. In your case, I'd probably go with **company.newsletter**.

See: http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/the-naming-of-things-package-names-and-namespaces for more information.

Comment: Hum, that martin aspeli link was exactly what I was looking for, I've read it in the past but couldn't remember. Thanks!